# How to do Horizontal Partitioning in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have Column1 in table TestBit. Column1 is a bit. I am trying to do Horizontal Partioning on Column1. So the record with bit true is seperated from the record with bit false. So Far I have tried this but unable to work.

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION SeparateBit (bit)
AS RANGE LEFT
FOR VALUES ('true')


CREATE PARTITION SCHEME TestBit
AS PARTITION SeparateBit
TO ([PRIMARY],FG2)


CREATE TABLE TestBit
(Column1 bit)
ON TestBit (Column1);

INSERT INTO TestBit (Column1)
values('true')

select partition_id, index_id, partition_number, Rows 
FROM sys.partitions
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID)='TestBit'
```

While selecting all rows count is appearing in same `partition_id`

Comment: Try using `FOR VALUES ('FALSE')` in the definition of the partition function or `RANGE RIGHT`.